# robots.txt allows all urls

Tags: seo, robots.txt

robots.txt

```
# robots.txt

User-agent: *
Disallow: */admin/*

Disallow: */Edit/*
Disallow: */edit/*

Disallow: */SendEmailToResetPassword/*

Disallow: */GetBidsAndComments/*
Disallow: */User/GetLoginUserId/*

Disallow: */Account/SendEmailToResetPassword/*
Disallow: */DeleteConfirmed/*
```

Testing using the `robots.txt tester` from `google search console`.

Urls it allows:

1. http://www.exp.com/ClassifiedAds/DeleteConfirmed/22c1c7b6-e114-4f29-8844-d3ae5e89950b

   2. http://www.exp.com/Account/SendEmailToResetPassword?ReturnUrl=%2Fitem%2Fhome-appliances-80b30b83-7ba9-4565-9e44-0d40d3f7f1d6
   3. http://www.exp.com/api/Electronic/GetBidsAndComments?id=51426&_=1548892800023

How can I disallow these urls?

Comment: I think this question is on-topic here, as no SEO advice is needed. -- Please [edit] your question to include a few example URLs you want to block (using `example.com` as domain).

Comment: I have added the urls that it should block, please check